# Infer child component generics from parent type

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I would like to create a table component which utilizes components to define the columns like this:

```
interface UsageModel {
  title: string;
}

const Usage = () => {
  const data: UsageModel[] = [{ title: "Stack Overflow" }]
  return <Table data={data}>
    <TableField header="Title">{row => row.title}</TableField>
  </Table>
}
```

This works technically but Typescript doesn't know the type of `row` (resulting in `unknown`) which is kinda annoying because you have to explicitly type every field.
I was expecting Typescript to get the generic type because of the typed children prop of the table but I guess this doesn't work because of how JSX is implemented?

Does anyone know of a way to teach Typescript how to do this?

**EDIT:** I've created a Playground with a working example [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-ts-3gseie?file=index.tsx).

The table code (minus the implementation) looks like this:

```
import { Component, ReactElement, ReactNode } from "react"

export interface TableFieldProps<T> {
  children: ((row: T) => ReactNode) | ReactNode
  header?: ReactNode
}

export class TableField<T> extends Component<TableFieldProps<T>> {
}

export interface TableProps<T> {
  data: T[]
  children: TableFieldElement<T> | TableFieldElement<T>[]
}

type TableFieldElement<T> = ReactElement<TableFieldProps<T>, typeof TableField>

export function Table<T>({ data, children }: TableProps<T>) {
  return (<table/>)
}
```

The compiler options of typescript look like this:

```json
{
    "sourceMap": true,
    "declaration": false,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "target": "es2021",
    "module": "esnext",
    "jsx": "react-jsx",
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "resolveJsonModule": true
}
```

Comment: Could you please provide reproducible example in sandbox (for instance typescript playground) ? Do you expect only on  child  `TableField` in `Table` ? Or number of `TableFields` should be euqal of data['length'] ? You might be interested in currying, see [here](https://catchts.com/currying-components). Also, it is impossible to make children component depend on parents generic. This is not supported by current version of TS

Comment: I've created a new sandbox [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-ts-3gseie?file=index.tsx).
There will be one `TableField` for each column in the table.

Comment: I see two options here: [first](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-ts-lpvv1p?file=index.tsx) and [second](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-ts-83clyq?file=index.tsx). Let me know if it works for you

Comment: Ah I didn't know this syntax got merged, but this still forces me to type every `TableField` which is something I would prefer not to.
Syntax wise I do prefer the annotation in the arrow function instead of the generic component as I feel like it looks kinda wonky.

Comment: You're doing some weird anti-patterns here. You shouldn't pass in React JSX elements as children and then try and map over them? And access their `props` directly? What exactly are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: Why do you feel like this is an anti-pattern? 
This is also how react-router for example does the routing and I think it improves readability by a long shot instead of the usual "configuration-based" approach you see in table components.

Answer (score 3):

The best idea I came up with, rather than exporting a react functional component directly was to export a generic function that will return a react component and infer the generic types to the children.
This is possible, because we expect only a specific child type in the `<Table />` which is `<Column />` (or `<TableField />` in your case)

Take a look on the sandbox here:
https://codesandbox.io/s/wonderful-babbage-neqdyg

But basically, to simplify things, the idea is:

```
type ColumnType<T> = React.ReactElement<ColumnProps<T>>;

interface ColumnProps<T> {
  header?: React.ReactNode;
  children?: (row: T) => React.ReactNode;
}

interface TableProps<T> {
  data?: Array<T>;
  children?: ColumnType<T>[] | ColumnType<T>;
}

const createColumn = <T extends unknown>() => (props: ColumnProps<T>) => (<></>);

export const createTable = <T extends unknown>() => {
  const Table = (props: TableProps<T>) => {
    return (<table>{/* table rendering goes here */}</table>)
  };

  // here is the point where we infer the generic arg to a child
  Table.Column = createColumn<T>();

  return Table;
}
```

And the usage is:

```
import { createTable } from "./Table"

interface UsageModel {
  title: string;
}

const Table = createTable<UsageModel>();

const App = () => {
  return (<Table>
            <Table.Column header="Some title">{row => row.title}</Table.Column>
         </Table>)
}
```

Comment: Found this solution elegant enough. Thank you! I was going crazy with the lack of typing in child components :)